Late 80's/early 90's romantic comedy with a guy and his friend sneaking in a girl's house
I'm trying to identify a late 80's/early 90's romantic comedy. I saw it on Cinema Golden Choice back when I was living in Mexico between 1990 and 2000, and I think the translated title was something like "A Primera Vista" ("At First Sight", as in love). I remember some particular scenes and details, which I hope I'm not mixing with some other movie:
The plot revolved around some guy who fell in love with some girl and was trying to date her. He and his best friend had been at some big sports match some years earlier (I think it was baseball, and the New York Yankees might have been playing, but I'm not exactly sure) Paul Simon concert in Central Park. At this concert the friend told him something like "our future wives must be among these 10000 people (the spectators)".
I don't remember how he met her, but later in the movie the protagonist and his friend break into the girl's house at night and find her sleeping in her room. Apparently she's dreaming about someone and starts talking in her sleep, asking that person (by name) to kiss her. The protagonist decides to kiss her and she wakes up, but doesn't see them and goes back to sleep. The next day when they come across her she mentions the same name, and when asked who that is, she replies that it's her dog. (wtf?)
I think this same morning the protagonist decides to call in sick to work because he doesn't want to go. Instead he and his friend go get breakfast at a restaurant, but his boss goes to eat at the same place and finds them. Thinking on his feet, the friend starts discretely but vigorously kicking the protagonist in the testicles under the table, which fools the boss when he sees the protagonist's face in pain and thinks he is actually sick.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, for some reason that movie stuck with me and I've been unable to find any proof on IMDB or Google that it actually existed.

You were right about the film's title, it was called At First Sight. It's just known under a different name: Two Guys Talkin' About Girls from 1996 with Jonathan Silverman, Dan Cortese and Allison Smith.

In the tradition of "Diner," a mostly dialogue-oriented guys' comedy about two Long Island yuppie buddies named Lenny and Joey. Lenny's a timid romantic. Joey's a womanizing stud. So, when Lenny meets a new girl and thinks she might be the one, Joey takes it upon himself to prove to Lenny once and for all that his philosophy is right.

The scenes you mentioned are there, and you can see bits of them (the guys sneaking into her room, and the crotch kicking) in the trailer:



